# Capture the actual number value of a date

Tags: excel, vba, date, charts

,Hi,
I've created a macro that will create a simple gantt chart. I took this from a manual process I found on the web. In the manual process in order to set the chart to the lowest date the user is supposed to click on the start date and go to Format Cell, and temporarly change the format to General so he can see the real numeric value. Then in the chart he clicks on the dates and goes to Format Axis where in  the minimum/Fixed field he types in the number that he saw when he viewed the data in General.
I have tried DataValue but it only works if the date is text and not really a date. Also I see that I can do `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = valuehere` to put in the value. But I can not figure out how once I've selected the cell with the date to automatically find out the number value and to put it in the line. I'm assuming that I capture the number somehow, put it in a variable and then in the above code line I put the variable in place of "valuehere" but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ValueHere = Format(ActiveCell.Value,"0")
```

Comment: Okay, both answers work as far if I put the ValueHere in a message box. But I still get a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. I've tried seting ValueHere As Variant and change the code to With ActiveChar.Axes(xlValue). But no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the .mimimumScale to work with any cell reference or variable. Now I've tried so many things I think I need to delete the code and start over so I know where I am :-) However, in a msgbox both of the examples work.

Comment: If you got an answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. It sounds like you have another question about an unitialized object, judging by your error. If you ask a question about that, be sure to post the relevant code so that you get a clear answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
valueHere = Range("A1").Value * 1
```